# Sleep, hibernate additional condition in Windows

Tags: windows, power-management

Is there a way to set an condition to not sleep/hibernate on Windows based systems if the particular app/process is running?

Comment: Why don't you just disable those features and if you want to sleep/hibernate the system do so manually?

Comment: I do that now, but this solution is often inconvenient, because I have to remember about doing that. Another problem is when I run some app/script, machine is going to sleep/hibenate in a half of execution. If timers are off the computer may works unnecessarily for hours (I'm not near). I don't know if there is a way to configure power-plan to such conditions?